Validity of using Hausman-McFadden Test results for addressing departures from the Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives (IIA)
The context is running a multinomial logit model with primary interest in measuring the effect of a case-specific variable A on a multinomial outcome B. Running Hausman-McFadden Tests shows how the full model differs from each model where the alternatives of B are reduced (how much IIA is violated). Ideally, the coefficients do not change.
My question is, would it be sufficient to use these tests and comparisons to show how much IIA is violated while arguing that effects that persist across these changes remain valid? For example, say out of 5 coefficients, 4 do not vary or do not vary by much but 1 does, or for all coefficients, the direction does not vary across reduced models.
